# Which Hibernate Jars are needed for JPA 2.1 support?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, jar

I am starting working on my first JPA project and I will be using Hibernate. I have downloaded the `hibernate-release-4.3.9.Final.zip` file from http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/ website which mentions that Hibernate 4.3.9.Final version supports JPA 2.1.

I have unzip this file and there are 35 Jar files in it. These are the locations of those 35 Jars:

- 1 Jar in `lib\envers` folder.
- 1 Jar in `lib\jpa` folder.
- 1 Jar in `lib\jpa-metamodel-generator` folder.
- 3 Jars in `lib\optional\c3p0` folder.
- 3 Jars in `lib\optional\ehcache` folder.
- 9 Jars in `lib\optional\infinispan` folder.
- 2 Jars in `lib\optional\proxool` folder.
- 3 Jars in `lib\osgi` folder.
- 10 Jars in `lib\required` folder.
- 1 Jar in `project\gradle\wrapper` folder.
- 1 Jar in `project\hibernate-osgi\src\test\resources\bnd` folder.

My question is which Hibernate Jars are needed for JPA 2.1 support? 
I am sure that **1 Jar in `lib\jpa` folder** is definitely needed. But what other Jars are needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Hibernate core with JPA 2.1 support the jars in required folder are alone enough:

From the maven repository :

[image]

The other jars as said are optional and can be added to the classpath on a need basis.For instance you want caching and want to use ehcache as your cache provider, then you can add ehcache jar to the classpath. Or c3p0 for connection pooling.

**If you just need JPA with hibernate's implementation , then you need to have the following in your classpath:**

DOC: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/pr01.html

[image]